# Swiftui fix view

Tags: swift, swiftui

as you see from the ui below there seems to be a square superimposed on a vstack with a round how to remove the white back part?

**UI:**
[image]
**SwitUi Code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct PresenzeUiView: View {
    @Binding var users: [UserTable]
    @State private var progressbarui = 20.0
    @State private var dettaglioPresenzaShow = false
    
    func getDate() -> String {
        let MyFormatter = DateFormatter()
        MyFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
        var date = MyFormatter.string(from: Date())
        return "" + date
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Oggi").multilineTextAlignment(.leading).colorInvert()
                    .font(.title2)
                    .fixedSize()
                Text(getDate())
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading).colorInvert()
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fixedSize()
                
                Text("Personale non in attività")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading).colorInvert()
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .fixedSize().padding(.top, 10)
                
                ProgressView("", value: progressbarui, total: 100).accentColor(Color.red).frame(height: 80)
                
            }.frame(width: 250).cornerRadius(20)
                .padding()
                .overlay(
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                        .stroke(.white, lineWidth: 5)
                )
            
        }.background(Color.white).frame(width: UIScreen.screenWidth - 300, height: UIScreen.screenHeight)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two notes:

1. You currently have two nested `VStack`s. You're adding the rounded corners to the inner one and setting the background on the outer one. If you need the outer `VStack`, make sure you set the shape on the outer one as well. If not, consider removing the outer one and setting the background on the one that's left. **Make sure you set the background *before* clipping the shape!**
2. Use `clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))` instead of `overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))`. Using `overlay` creates a secondary View over the first one, which is why you can still see the original view underneath.

Comment: ok but how can fix code?